# How to enable amd-v from command line?

Tags: 64-bit, virtualization

Is it possible to enable AMD-V feature from command line?

I've a Phenom II X4 laptop and I forget the bios password, hence looking for alter solution.

Answer (score 1):

Get the manual for the mainboard in your laptop and check if the vendor provided a procedure for resetting the BIOS password. If not, try removing the CMOS battery (if the mainboard has a removable one) for a couple seconds. That should also reset the BIOS. The location of the battery should be described in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

You don't enable it from the command line. It must be enabled from the BIOS.

If you forgot your BIOS password, work on that problem first.